# Replace rest of STR to 0 on STR

Tags: php

I don't know what question should be,

I have int that need to split like this

```
$value = 123454
```

I wan't result like this

```
100000
20000
3000
400
50
4
```

currently I do like this

```
public function displaySong($value){

    $strvalue = strval($value);
    $len = strlen($strvalue);

    for ($x = 0; $x <= $len; $x++) {
        $str = substr($strvalue, $x);
        echo "The number is: $str \n";
    } 


    echo $len."\n";
    echo $strvalue[1]."\n";
}
```

how to make it work? or any have better solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the place value for the given decimal value through php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801703/how-to-find-the-place-value-for-the-given-decimal-value-through-php)

Comment: I have a solution, but what is the goal of this?

Comment: @Manngo one can hazard a guess that it is for displaying a song.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$value = '123454';

$array = str_split($value, 1);

$array = array_reverse($array);

array_walk($array, function(&$a, $b){

  $a = $a . str_repeat('0', $b);

});

$array = array_reverse($array);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100000
    [1] => 20000
    [2] => 3000
    [3] => 400
    [4] => 50
    [5] => 4
)
```

Comment: Funky way of avoiding a count or length call.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$value = (string) 123454;
$len   = strlen($value);

for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
    echo str_pad($value[$i], $len - $i, '0') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
100000
20000
3000
400
50
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly season one liner:

```
<?php
echo implode("\n",
    array_map(
        function($v, $k) {
            return str_pad($v, $k, 0);
        },
        $digits = str_split(123454),
        range(count($digits), 1, -1)
    )
);
```

Output:

```
100000
20000
3000
400
50
4
```