# php Expressing numbers in expanded form array

Tags: php, arrays

I want input number to that number real power output

like `212` is input and output real power of `200` + `10` + `2`

This method is also called expanded form.

Numbers in expanded form like:

```
$input = 5362;
```

I want output like this:

```
5000,300,60,2
```

I am trying to find many solution but fail.

Please give me code example if anyone understands my problem.

My code coding attempt is in python, but I am seeking a php solution.

```
user_input = 12345
result = []
for i, num in enumerate(str(user_input)[::-1]): result.append(f'{num} * {10 ** i}')
    print(' + '.join(result[::-1]))
```

Comment: Can you show one of your nearest solutions and we can see where you are going wrong and able to help.

Comment: yes brother am find one solution in python but python is not for our project so  am share with you paython code for just idea      user_input = 12345

result = []
for i, num in enumerate(str(user_input)[::-1]):
    result.append(f'{num} * {10 ** i}')

print(' + '.join(result[::-1]))

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25801703/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```php
$input = 5362;

$array = str_split($input);
krsort($array);
$array = array_map(function($number, $key){
    return str_pad($number, $key + 1, '0');
}, $array, array_keys(array_values($array)));
krsort($array);

print_r(implode(',', $array));
```

Result:

```
5000,300,60,2
```

Comment: Please never post "try this" answers on Stack Overflow.  Every answer should include an educational explanation with the intent to educate and empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Comment: mick   sir    you think all students  perfect in english language not if you think all is perfect please again think on your think   my english is poor so am trying hard to make my self perfect thanks for guide

Comment: @qaiserjutt a broken English explanation will ALWAYS be better than no explanation.  If you cannot speak any English, then there is Google translate which will produce, at worst, broken English.

Comment: `krsort()` is more sensible written as `array_reverse()`.  This snippet lacks elegance.

Answer (score 2):

Another, perhaps simpler approach might be:

```
$a = 5362;
$length = strlen($a);
foreach (str_split($a) as $item) {
    $result[] = $item * 10 ** --$length;
}
echo implode(',', $result);
```

Process explained:

1. store string length
2. go through the string being split into an array of chars
3. process current digit: multiply it by `10^<number of zeroes>`, while decrementing the value
4. store currently processed digit into a result array
5. use `implode` to join array elements into a CSV string

Demo: https://3v4l.org/BLcde